# How to access an application deployed in tomcat via domain name in URL instead of IP

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, server, debian

I installed tomcat 9.0.7 in my Linux Debian 9 machine. I want to access the application in the tomcat server via domain name.
For example: I want to use `www.standoutjava.com/manager/html` instead of `localhost:8080/manager/html`

I have changed my Connector setting in server.xml as follows so that I'm able to use the URL without port number.

```
   <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0"/>
```

Now i can access the applications like `localhost/manager/html` or `192.168.40.29/manager/html`

But its not enough I want to replace the IP portion with a certain domain name. So the URL will look like `http://www.standoutjava.com/manager/html`

I have changed my server.xml as follows.

```html
      GNU nano 2.7.4                          File: server.xml                                     


        <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
             and responses are returned. Documentation at :
             Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
             Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
             APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
             Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
        -->
       <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0"/>
        <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
        <!--
        <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
                   port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" />
        -->
        <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
                This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
       <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
   -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" 
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>

      <Host name="www.standoutjava.com" appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="www.standoutjava.com_access_log" suffix=".txt"
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Also I changed the hosts file (etc/hosts) in the machine as follows.

```html
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
192.168.40.29   www.standoutjava.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Now I'm able to access the URL as `http://www.standoutjava.com/manager/html` from the same computer where the tomcat get installed. But i can't access the URL from another computer in my network.

So what should i do to access the URL over the network?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Make tomcat listening on a local port (on localhost, ideally with ajp), and make your apache to be a proxy for it.